# Finding the 404 page template of a website

Tags: 404, website-features

Is there a certain technique or make my life easier in finding the 404 page template of a website?

What I do right now to find a 404 page on a specific website is to visit the website and edit their URL by adding a fake page. Then it will return the 404 page.

Comment: Not sure why you would *want* to go around cataloging 404 pages but to each their own.

Comment: Your method sounds like the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

There's a multitude of ways to generate a 404 page so there really isn't one true answer to this.  404 pages can be generated using the web server default.  They can be named anything on the server and the server or site can be configured to serve it up.  They can be static HTML pages with a simple name or dynamically generated beasties whose content is generated by database calls.

In very general terms you would have some luck appending `/404.html` or `/404.(insert extension that the site runs here)` but you would have almost a 100% hit rate just adding a long garbage string to the domain name: `thesite.com/WHARRGARBL`

Of course, the latter technique will also get your IP banned by site operators who check their logs on a regular basis...

Comment: Thank you @JCL1178, i am doing this because I am working on a blog post that showcase creative 404 pages. "thesite.com/WHARRGARBL" is what im doing right now, im just wondering if there's another way. thank you again!

Comment: In this case the "another way" would have been to contact the site owners, explain your project, and ask them to help you with a demo.  Dynamic 404 pages can do all sorts of things based on what you were trying to access and the current approach of feeding garbage to the site may not result in the best example for you to use. Working with people instead of just randomly generating a 404 would also prevent any IP blacklisting...they would know who you are and why you are showing up in the error logs.

Comment: /offtopic @JCL1178 (http://qandasys.info/finding-the-404-page-of-a-website/),  coincidence!?
/Ontopic, often is going to a website clicking just a link to look at a page and taking off/out a character of the pagename already enough to show an error page. No reason to ban some ip for that imho, if sites would do that before they see you "did" some more than 3 times in a row most sites would not have much trafic soon anymore imho. As soon a 404 is showing just making a screengrab is already enough to use in a showcase. (after you asked the web-owner for permission ofcourse! (copyright it is!))

Comment: @Charles I don't know what that site is. Looks like a scraper. As far as "No reason to ban some ip for that imho" it all depends on how you do it and how often. If you are doing it manually, then odds are no one will notice. If you attempt to use a script to do it and I see 10-20 404's with nonsense page names in a short time span in my logs, I might ban the IP just to be safe.